# tkinter main window matplotlib figure embeded on a canvas affecting a toplevel window figure embede on a different canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, mysql-python

I have a tkinter main window(main_window), toplevel(db_window), and another toplevel (Analysis_window). on the main_window I have embedded a Matplotlib figure over a frame as shown below:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (20, 6), dpi = 80, constrained_layout = True)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_title("Electrocadiogram")
ax.set_xlabel("Time(Sec)")
ax.set_ylabel("Voltage(mV)")
for label in  ax.get_xticklabels():
       label.set_rotation(40)
       label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=plotting_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1170, height = 420)
```

[image: main_window]

and on the analysis_window have embedded over a different frame as show below:

```
my_fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize = (12, 6), dpi = 80, constrained_layout = True)
    my_ax1 =  my_fig1.add_subplot()
    #my_ax1.set_title("Electrocadiogram")
    my_ax1.set_xlabel("Time(hh:mm:ss)")
    #my_ax1.set_ylabel("Voltage(mV)")
    for label in  my_ax1.get_xticklabels():
       label.set_rotation(40)
       label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
    my_ax1.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
    my_ax1.minorticks_on()
    my_ax1.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#666666', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
    my_canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg( my_fig1, master=analyzer_frame)
    my_canvas1.draw()
    my_canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 920, height = 650)
```

[image: analysis_window]

to my surprise, the way the figure on main_window is behaving also the figure on the analysis window behaves the same, and it acquires labels from the figure on the main window(more like the figure on the main_window is duplicated on an analysis_window. have tried to maneuver here and there but I can't understand what's happening and have also checked online but am unable to find what's going on. can someone help me undestand?

Comment: You used same ID `1` in both figure.  Remove the first argument, `1`, from both `plt.figure(1, ...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 it's done thank you very much